# Type of return in do block

Tags: haskell, types, return, monads

I am trying to understand Monads in Haskell and during my countless experiments with code I have encountered this thing:

```
f2 = do   
  return "da"
```

and the fact that it doesnt want to compile with huge error regarding type. I think the only important part is this:

```
 No instance for (Monad m0) arising from a use of return'
The type variable `m0' is ambiguous
```

So then I have changed my code to:

```
 f2 = do   
 return "da"  :: IO [Char]
```

And it worked perfectly well. But when I have tried to mess up a bit and change the type to IO Int it was an error once again. So why the type is "ambiguous" when it actually isnt?
Also when I will add something before return like:

```
f2 = do   
  putStrLn "das"  
  return 2
```

Then I dont have to specify the type of return. 
So can someone explain me what is going on really? Also why is return outputting "da" in the first case? Not da without ""?

Comment: Thanks for editing my stuff jozefg I was struggling to do it myslef!

Comment: No problem, welcome to stackoverflow and Haskell :)

Comment: That is close to the smallest possible type error message, plus some extra advice provided by the friendly compiler. Type errors can get much much larger!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First let's just point out that

```
do
  return a
```

Is exactly the same as

```
return a
```

Now, the problem is that `return` has the type

```
return :: Monad m => a -> m a
```

And when you have a declaration like

```
foo = bar
```

where `foo` has no arguments haskell makes it "monomorphic". The result of this is that Haskell can't guess what `m` is and won't generalize it so you need an explicit type signature. The most general one is

```
f2 :: Monad m => m String
f2 = return "das"
```

But you could also use `IO` or any other monad

```
f2 :: IO String
```

Finally, in your last example, since you're returning `2`, you'd have to give a type signature that indicates you're returning some sort of number, like

```
 f2 :: IO Integer
```

Comment: This leaves out why you don't need a type signature for `f2`, even though it's also monomorphic.  The answer is that `putStrLn` constrains the monad to be `IO`, so the most general type would be `f2 :: Num n => IO n`.  This isn't monomorphic either, but Haskell has [defaulting rules](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/decls.html#default-decls) for the numeric types, and these will fix `n` to be `Integer` if you don't specify a type signature.

Answer (score 5):

This is known [Monomorphism_restriction](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monomorphism_restriction)

Use signatures

```
f2 :: Monad m => m String
f2 = do   
  return "da"
```

or use language extension:

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}
f2 = do   
  return "da"
```

to get valid code

Answer (score 4):

When learning about monads it's helpful to expand them out manually yourself, for instance the simple example:

```
test0 :: IO String
test0 = do
  a <- getLine
  putStrLn a
  return a
```

If we enable the language extension `{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}` then we can annotate each of the lines in the monad with it's explicit type which will show the type of the return block.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

test1 :: IO String
test1 = do
  a <- getLine             :: IO String
  putStrLn a               :: IO ()
  return a                 :: IO String
```

We can also annotate the explicit type of the left hand side pattern matching which "extracts" from the monad context on the right hand side.

```
test2 :: IO String
test2 = do
  (a :: String) <- getLine  :: IO String
  (() :: ()) <- putStrLn a  :: IO ()
  return a                  :: IO String
```

We can even expand out the do-notation into its constituting parts:

```
test3 :: IO String
test3 = getLine >>=
        (\a -> putStrLn a >>=
        \() -> return a)
```

Hope that helps build your monad intuition.