# transforming ghci snippet to a script

Tags: haskell

I've came up with this:

```
Prelude> let a = \x -> print x
Prelude> let b = \x -> return x
Prelude> b 123 >>= a
123
```

My problem is, script version does not compile:

```
monad_1.hs:2:11:
    No instance for (Monad m0) arising from a use of ‘return’
    The type variable ‘m0’ is ambiguous
    Relevant bindings include b :: a -> m0 a (bound at monad_1.hs:2:1)
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance Monad Maybe -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’
      instance Monad IO -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’
      instance Monad ((->) r) -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’
      ...plus one other
    In the expression: return x
    In the expression: \ x -> return x
    In an equation for ‘b’: b = \ x -> return x
```

Comment: I think this is a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20690304/578411

Comment: Could you show your script?